# Make serial gnu-screen send a line at once

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-port

Is it possible to send lines at once in linux `screen` utility, if used as serial terminal, like for example `screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600`?

By default, every character typed is sent immediately, but my serial device require a complete message 'at once', eg. send uninterrupted at actual serial line speed.